# Managing Multiple teams when we have single / multiple development servers in Siebel

Tags: concurrency, siebel

We have several teams working on different work packages involving same objects with single development server. My question:  how can we mangae this kind of situations without losing the time of the resources. To elaborate more, I have two teams working on Account BC with different change orders with same release date and I want the work to be done in parallel. What are the best ways to handle this situation and my answer is we need to wait and not possible. Does any one have the solution to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Have both teams develop with an offline copy of the Accounts BC - sharing the object between themselves as a SIF file. Merge the two streams together with the Tools archive import function.

Answer (score 0):

Create an new object manager for the server which has its srf point to one other than siebel_sia. Create as many users and mobile clients as the developers. Get them the extracted database on thier client names. Make on team work on main object manager (_enu) and get the other work on (_custom). Bouncing individual object managers as the development cycle continues